# How to hide the "console tab menu" in Chrome DevTools

Tags: google-chrome, console, google-chrome-devtools

Is there any way I can hide this menu? It takes too much space on a laptop, especially when I want to have the console window and network tab simultaneously on the side:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just click on the blue cog on the top right